# Subquery between two objects

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have two different models Department and employee

```
@interface Department : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Employee> *employee; 

@end


@interface Employee : RLMObject

@property NSString *department;
@property NSString *email;
@property NSString *firstname;
@property NSString *lastname;
@property NSString *fullname;
@property NSString *imgUrl;
@property NSString *imgWall;
@property NSString *nickname;

@end
```

I want to search which department of employee has contains "a" in their first name and last name. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd like to do is as follows:

```
RLMResults *r = [Department objectsWhere:
                 @"SUBQUERY(employee, $e, $e.firstname CONTAINS 'a' AND $e.lastname CONTAINS 'a').@count > 0"];
```